# Chrome access/request log

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

I'm looking for a way to output requests and their response codes from Chrome. Basically I would like what is in the Network tab in developer tools in a log file or accessible from outside of Chrome.

I tried starting Chrome with `--enable-logging --v=1` but I cannot find any traces of accessed urls.

Is there a way I can get that logging?

Comment: Use the Chrome DevTools protocol ( https://chromedevtools.github.io/devtools-protocol/tot/Network ) and capture the information there?

Comment: @Corion Looks promising. I'll try that!